# Reading values with xlwings in a loop

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have a program that reads data from an Excel workbook continuously. It runs in while loop that is limited by time, that is it runs about 8 hours.

There were some breakdown, while I opened the workbook on each iteration, like this:

```
workbook = xw.Book("file_name")
```

So, I put it outside the loop and a lot of the errors went away.

What about loading the separate sheets. Is it advisable to do it in each iteration, or should I save them as objects outside the loop and then just use range on this objects?

I understand from Excel Object Model that the sheets are part of a collection, hence they might more difficult to retrieve on each iteration.

It is a bit faster if I load outside of loop, but no a huge difference.

Comment: Likely outside the loop.

Comment: So, your question is if it is better to loop over worksheets of a workbook or to assign worksheets to variables? If that is your question, both is possible. You could use `for sheet in workbook.sheets:` or you could use `ws1 = workbook.sheets[0]`, `ws2 = workbook.sheets[1]`. Some more context would be helpful.

Comment: @BigBen that is my guess as well, however I would like to be more informed of it, as there is a lot of code I would need to change.

Comment: @mouwsy No, I have a while loop that is time limited(it runs 8 hours). I am wondering whether it is better to load worksheets inside the loop or just assign them to variables before the loop.